# Putting names and numbers from a text file into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

There is a list of ranks, names, and popularity  1 Jake 21021 (rank, the actual name, how many babies were given that name that year)  I am trying to take these three separate things, and divide them up into arrays. That way if a user searches for "Jake" rank: 1 pops up and so does 21021.  This is what i have so far...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/boynames.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry we couldn't find the requested file...");
            System.out.println("Exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //Initializing the BOY Variables
        int[] counter = new int[1];
        String[] name = new String[1];
        int[] popularity = new int[1];
        //End of initializing BOY variables
        for (int i=0; i <1000;i++)
        {
            counter[0] = 1;
            name[i] = inputStream.next();
            popularity[i]=inputStream.nextInt();
            System.out.print(counter[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + popularity[i] );
            counter[i] = counter[i] + 1 ;
        }
    }
}
```

i keep getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

any help would be awesome!
thanks

Comment: you should look into a `Map` you can create a new class to hold all the information and use the `Name` as a key. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialized `name` as an array of size 1, but then you reference `name[i]`, where `i` is counting up to 1000.  `name[0]` works, but as soon as you reach `name[1]`, you get the exception.

You should initialize `name` as `String[1000]`. Or (better yet) use an ArrayList, which expands as you add items to it.

Comment: How would i use ArrayList would i have to define it as a separate class or is it a built in method?

Comment: ArrayList (java.util.ArrayList) is a built-in java collections object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

since name array's length is 1, the max index of name is 0. so during the next loop iteration when i=1, this line will be out of bounds.

```
name[i] = inputStream.next();
```

Comment: okay -- i have it printing out all the names with the order
rank, name, how many times the name was used -- how do i see if they have been put into arrays?

Comment: int[] counter = new int[1000];
  String[] name = new String[1000];
  int[] popularity = new int[1000];
  //End of initializing BOY variables
  for (int i=0; i <1000;i++)
  {
   name[i] = inputStream.next();
   popularity[i]=inputStream.nextInt();
   counter[i] = i+1;
   System.out.print(counter[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + popularity[i] +"\n");
  }

Comment: i made the legnths equal to 1000 so that it can print everything... but really what i want the program to do is store the array and have them searchable

Comment: I think you want to do a name->popularity search. Look at using a java Dictionary class

Comment: Zac - If you've corrected the error that caused you to ask this question, you should accept an answer and then ask a new question about your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, you're creating arrays of size 1 (`new int[1]`, etc), and then trying to access indexes 0-999 inside your for loop. If you want an array to have 1000 positions in it, like your for loop requires, then you should create an array such as `new int[1000]`.